# Python/bash wget file and see if contents matches unix timestamp

Tags: python, bash, scripting, timestamp

Scenario

One web server user hits execute that will produce a file called now.txt and inside this file will current unix timestamp

On the current machines I need a way to check if that file has a timestamp that is within 5 minutes on its current time and if say execute another command

I was thinking of having a `cronjob` running on the client machine every 5 minutes that will do a `wget` of the file from the webserver then check the contents for its unix timestamp then compare it with the current time

Not sure if that makes sense and not sure if I have over egged it so would be good to get some advice?

Python script

```
wget file
check file is with 5 minutes of current time 
run another command




import wget
from datetime import datetime;

url = 'http://example.com/test/now.txt'
filename = wget.download(url) 

try:

        f = open("now.txt", "rb");
        age = datetime.utcnow() - datetime.utcfromtimestamp(long(f.read()));
except :
        pass
```

Comment: Are you relying on the system time on the server and the client being in sync?  That's unlikely.

Comment: It does not sound to be over-egged. I'd prefer to do this in python, not in bash. Look at the requests library. Do you have any concrete question? Because it is not clear what is being asked here.

Comment: If you are dealing with a web server here - wouldn't it be easier to have clients send a simple request and execute (or not) some code based on the response?

Comment: I'm not sure about the purpose, do you intend to build some sort of  heartbeat? In python it's real easy: `from datetime import datetime; f = open("now.txt", "rb"); age = datetime.utcnow() - datetime.utcfromtimestamp(long(f.read()));` Also: clock sync between client and server is assumed.

Comment: Thanks all, yes python looks like the useful way to do - It can be viewed as heartbleed to see if a script needs to be run depending on the unix time with a file

Comment: So what's the question exactly?

Comment: Suppose the questions is how to do the logic for between 5 minutes with a unix timestamp and if there is a better method then above

Comment: What are you trying to do? Read [the description of XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096). Does it look like your case?

Answer (score 0):

To read a Unix timestamp that is saved in a remote file and to compare it with the current time on the client (assuming the clocks are synchronized e.g., using ntp):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen 

with urlopen('http://example.com/test/now.txt') as r:
   timestamp = int(r.read())
   if abs(time.time() - timestamp) < 300:
       print('the current time is within 5 minutes')
```